# Let $F$ be a class of sets. Prove that $B - \mathop{\bigcup}_{A\in F} A = \mathop{\bigcap}_{A\in F} (B-A)$

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Let $F$ be a class of sets. Prove that  $B - \mathop{\bigcup}_{A\in F} A = \mathop{\bigcap}_{A\in F} (B-A)$

I've started like this:

$X= B - \mathop{\bigcup}_{A\in F} A$

$Y= \mathop{\bigcap}_{A\in F} (B-A)$

If $x\in X$, then $x\in B\land x\notin \mathop{\bigcup}_{A\in F} A$

Think that I should show that $X\subseteq Y$ and $Y\subseteq X$

But I have no idea what $\mathop{\bigcap}_{A\in F} (B-A)$ means.

Could anybody explain it's meaning? And am I going in the right direction with the proof?

Comment: The claim sounds wrong if $F$ is the empty class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in B - \bigcup_{A\in F}A$

$\Longleftrightarrow x\in B \wedge x \notin \bigcup_{A\in F}A$

$\Longleftrightarrow x\in B \wedge x \notin A, \forall A\in F$

$\Longleftrightarrow x \in B-A,\forall A \in F$

$\Longleftrightarrow x \in \bigcap_{A\in F}(B-A).$

$\therefore B - \bigcup_{A\in F}A = \bigcap_{A\in F}(B-A).$

$\bigcap_{A\in F}(B-A)$ means: Take all sets $A_i$ of $F$ and perform $B-A_i$ for every $i$. Then intersect the results from the last step: $\bigcap_{A\in F}(B-A)=\{x:x\in(B-A),\forall A \in F\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The *meaning* of the $\bigcap$ symbol is intersection (just like $\bigcup$ denotes union), that is
$$\tag1 x\in\bigcap_{A\in F}(B-A)\iff \forall A\in F\colon x\in (B-A).$$
I suppose you can take it from here.

Note one exception heowever: If $F$ is the empty class, then by $(1)$ the intersection  automatically becomes $\bigcap_{A\in F}(B-A)$ the universal class, which is *not* the same as $B-\bigcup_{x\in F} A$. In fact, if you hadn't used the word "class" to begin with, I would have tolsd you that the  intersection over an empty index set is undefined.